# mysql column with auto-index?

Tags: mysql, database, create-table

How can I create a column which goes with the next entry to 2,3,4,5,6,7 and so on? Is this possible or have I to get the last id and then via PHP + 1 and insert it? Its for an editor with PHP.

My current configuration:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beitraege` (  
 `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,  
 `titel` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,  
 `inhalt` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the AUTO_INCREMENT propriety: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beitraege` (
`ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`titel` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
 `inhalt` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: just skip the id column during the insert. Let the db take care of it for you @MiroF.